# Xamarin log in to Apple account gets incorrect authorization

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019, ios-provisioning, apple-id

When I add my Apple account to xamarin, it seems to add correctly, but it shows ma as a user with “agent” authority not “admin” which is what I have. Then it says I have no permission to download certificates and profiles.
I am a single person “team” on Apple and have used this for years, but now, with VS2019 I can no longer download a provider profile.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug. For details, please refer to: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-load-Apple-certificates/1692185.

You can report a problem with the visual studio product or installer.For details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

It will be fixed in a later version.